# Debian - useradd: cannot open /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, debian

I cannot add new users to my debian system. It worked a couple of days ago but not sure what happened that it is not working anymore.

```
root@debian:~# rm /etc/.pwd.lock

root@debian:~# useradd -G users --create-home -p somepw someuser
useradd: cannot open /etc/passwd

root@debian:~# ls -al /etc/ | grep passwd
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root    1472 Jan 18 01:44 passwd
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root    1470 Jan 18 01:34 passwd-

root@debian:~# ls -al /etc/ | grep group
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root     711 Jan 18 01:34 group
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root     698 Jan 18 01:22 group-

root@:~# ls -al /etc/ | grep shadow
-rw-r-----  1 root  shadow   594 Jan 18 01:34 gshadow
-rw-r-----  1 root  shadow   584 Jan 18 01:22 gshadow-
-rw-r-----  1 root  shadow  1032 Jan 18 01:34 shadow
-rw-r-----  1 root  shadow   969 Jan 18 01:34 shadow-

root@debian:~# lsattr /etc/passwd
-----a--------e------- /etc/passwd

root@debian:~# lsattr /etc/shadow
-----a--------e------- /etc/shadow

root@debian:~# ls -alt /etc/.*lock
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Jan 19 10:23 /etc/.pwd.lock
```

The only thing I can remember I did was adding bash as default shell for a user (from that useraccount):

```
type -a bash
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

I read other questions and articles but none of the solutions worked for me. How can I further debug this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does "pwck" command show you?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this fixed it:

```
root@debian:~# chattr -a /etc/passwd
root@debian:~# chattr -a /etc/shadow
```

I also had to do it on the shadow file.